# Yesterday-access.log is pointing to a different directory

Tags: linux, log-files, ubuntu-12.04, logrotate, awstats

Under `/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/quotednews.com/` folder, the `yesterday-access.log` is pointing to a wrong directory. `yesterday-access.log` is just a symlink to: `/var/www/clients/client1/web2/log/20130626-access.log`.

The correct value should be:

```
yesterday-access.log -> /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log/20130626-access.log
```

It should be web3 and not web2.

The same thing happen also under `/var/www/clients/client1/web3/log/` folder. The `yesterday-access.log` is pointing to `/var/www/clients/client1/web2/log/20130626-access.log`.

The correct value should be:

```
yesterday-access.log -> /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log/20130626-access.log
```

That's why the log file of web2 folder is affected. That is, it was overwritten by web3 user and awstats cannot create the correct stats for mydomain.com.

Web2 is using a different site.

The example of this are:

```
mydomain.com = /var/www/clients/client1/web2
example.com = /var/www/clients/client1/web3
```

But I'm wondering why example.com is using the mydomain.com's log file.

Anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove the soft link

yesterday-access.log -> var/www/clients/client1/web2/log/20130626-access.log

under /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log/

Comment: here it is:  [link](http://pastebin.com/4jZd13EF) and [link](http://pastebin.com/8RsNKtjj)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz I needed a bit more information before I could give a good answer.